# DirectShow video playing too fast when audio pin rendering data

Tags: c++, directshow

I'm working on a custom Windows DirectShow source filter based on CSource and CSourceStream for each pin. There are two pins - video output and audio output. Both pins work fine when individually rendered in graphedit and similar tools such as Graph Studio with correct time stamps, frame rates and sound. I'm rendering the video to the Video Mixing Renderer (VMR7 or VMR9).

However when I render both pins the video plays back too fast while the audio still sounds correct. The video plays back approximately 50% too fast but I think this is limited by the speed of decoding.

The timestamps on the samples are the same in both cases. If I render the audio stream to a null renderer (the one in qedit.dll) then the video stream plays back at the correct frame rate. The filter is a 32 bit filter running on a Win7 x64 system.

When I added support for IMediaSeeking seeking I found that the seeking bar for the audio stream behaved quite bizarrely. However the problem happens without IMediaSeeking support.

Any suggestions for what could be causing this or suggestions for further investigation?

The output types from the audio and video pin are pasted below:

Mediatyp: Video     Subtype: RGB24  Format: Type VideoInfo Video Size: 1024 x 576 Pixel, 24 Bit Image Size: 1769472 Bytes Compression: RGB Source: width 0, height 0 Target: width 0, height 0 Bitrate: 0 bits/sec. Errorrate: 0 bits/sec. Avg. display time: 41708 µsec.

Mediatyp: Video     Subtype: RGB32  Format: Type VideoInfo Video Size: 1024 x 576 Pixel, 32 Bit Image Size: 2359296 Bytes Compression: RGB Source: width 0, height 0 Target: width 0, height 0 Bitrate: 0 bits/sec. Errorrate: 0 bits/sec. Avg. display time: 41708 µsec.

Majortyp: Audio
Subtype: PCM audio
Sample Size: 3
Type WaveFormatEx
Wave Format: Unknown
Channels: 1
Samples/sec.: 48000
Avg. bytes/sec.:144000
Block align: 3
Bits/sample: 24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised the problem straight after posting the question. A case of debugging by framing the question correctly.

The audio stream had completely bogus time stamps. The audio and video streams played back fine individually but did not synch at all with each other when played together.